# Speed up massive insertion with subqueries for foreign keys

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have to insert massive data (from a Python programme into a SQLite DB), where many fields are validated via foreign keys.

The query looks like this, and I perform the insertion with executemany()

```
INSERT INTO connections_to_jjos(
    connection_id,
    jjo_error_id,
    receiver_task_id
    sender_task_id
)
VALUES
(
    :connection_id,
    (select id from rtt_errors where name = :rtx_error),
    (select id from tasks where name = :receiver_task),
    (select id from tasks where name = :sender_task)
)
```

About 300 insertions take something like 15seconds, which I think it way too much. In production, there should be blocks of 1500 insertions in bulk or so. In similar cases without subqueries for the foreign keys, speed is unbelievable. It's quite clear that FK's will add overhead and slow down the process, but this is too much.

I could do a pre-query to catch all the foreign key id's, and then insert them directly, but I feel there must be a cleaner option.

On the other hand, I have read about the [Isolation level](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#controlling-transactions), and if I don't understand it wrong, it could be that before each SELECT query, there is an automated COMMIT to enforce integrity... that could result in slowing down the process as well, but my attempts to work in this way were totally unsuccessful.

Maybe I'm doing something essentially wrong with the FK's. How can I improve the performance?

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

The query:

`EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN select id from rtt_errors where name = '--Unknown--'`

Outputs:

```
SEARCH TABLE
    rtt_errors

USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_rtt_errors_1 (name=?) (~1 rows)
```

I have created an index in rtt_errors.name, but apparently it is not using it.

Comment: What is the output of `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN select id from rtt_errors where name = 42` and the other queries?

Comment: I have added the information at the bottom.

Comment: I guess you already have a `UNIQUE` constraint on `name`? Also in the `tasks` table?

Comment: Yes, it's true, each "name" column is `UNIQUE`. This entails an index.

Comment: Try setting autocommit mode, and then executing explicit `BEGIN`/`COMMIT` commands once around all the `INSERT`s.

Comment: Hi, I set isolation_level=None, and then I wrapped all my queries by one .execute('BEGIN TRANSACTION') and .execute('COMMIT'). Now it works like a thunder. Thanks a lot! Write it as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, Python's default `COMMIT`s should not happen between consecutive `INSERT`s, but your extremely poor performance look as if this is what is happening.

Set the [isolation level](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#controlling-transactions) to `None`, and then execute a pair of `BEGIN`/`COMMIT` commands *once* around all the `INSERT`s.

Comment: I think the reason for the automatic commits, are the subqueries. These fetch information from another table, and sqlite commits prior to a select in order to keep consistence. Makes sense, but I don't run any inconstitence risk here, so it's unnecessary.